# Return unexpected number

Tags: javascript, html, oop

This is a code to control my character. "control" is a name of button class. Im using for loop to declare adding touch event listener. I had could change the color while its on touch. element on index 0 is for turn left, element on index 1 is for jump.

problem :
when i check the number of i variable with console log in touch event function, its return 15. I only had 4 element. 15 was not match on my cases.

My question is how the i variable returns 15?

```
var getControl = {
    buts : document.getElementsByClassName("control"),

    build : function(world){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){

            this.buts[i].addEventListener("touchstart",function(e){
                console.log(getControl.temp);
                e.preventDefault();
                this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                console.log(i);
                switch(i){
                    case 0:
                        misc[0].left();
                        console.log("left");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        misc[0].jump();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        misc[0].right();
                        break;
                    case 3:

                        break;
                };
            },false);
            this.buts[i].addEventListener("touchend",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            },false);
            this.buts[i].addEventListener("touchleave",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            },false);
```

Comment: How exactly, where and when do you check its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all `for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)` will declare `i` as global variable, so (assuming that you're doing that for all the loops in your code) `i` will have the value it got from the last executed `for` loop.

What you should do, for all the `for` loops in this code and future ones, is to declare the index `i` (or `j` or ...) like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
```

2. `for` loops will have the same scope throughout the whole iterations, so the closure will be messed up. Because all the event listeners will get a reference to the same `i`, so when they will get called they will try and see what value `i` have (even if you correct the problem **1.**, `i` will not have the value you expect because it will be changed after the reference to it was passed to the event listener. **for changed it by continually incrementing it**). What you need is a mechanism to create unique scopes for each item of the array. You can try this [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), or use an alternative to `for` like `forEach` (which is more or less similar to the solution in the link).

So this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    this.buts[i].addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
        // ...
```

should be replaced by this:

```
// since buts is an array-like object we can't use forEach directly but we could call it like this
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.buts, function(but, i) {
    but.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
        // you can use i here and it will work
    });
    // ...
    // but is equivalent to this.buts[i]
});
```

Comment: I had change the `i` into `j` and its return 4. Then on  `this.buts[i].forEach(function(but, i) {`  says that forEach is not a function.

Comment: @Alif I've just noticed that `buts` is not an array. (`document.getElementsByClassName`) return an **array-like** object not an **array**. I updated my answer, now it should work!

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you have

```
i=0
```

This declares i as a global variable, so it is probably being incremented or assigned somewhere else. The global namespace is dangerous.

Try making a variable in your function's scope like this:

```
var i = 0
```